# empty data when using json stringify html form results

Tags: javascript, json

When trying to send my from data to json.stringify() my alert results it comes back empty [].

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
        <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
        <script>
         formData = {};
          var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());

          $.ajax({
    url: "myurlfortesting.com",
    data: formData,
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);

    }
});
alert(formData)
</script>

  <body>

        <form class="myForm" id = "myForm" method="POST" >
            <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Store</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text"   name="store_code">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="example-number-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">companies</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="number"  name="company_code">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="example-number-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">People</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="number"   name="people_code">
          </div>


            <input value="Submit" type="submit">
        </form>
```

The alert is sending an empty []. The results i want after i click the form submit button in the alert is a stringified json object which looks like

```
'{"store_code": "New York", "company_code": 55, "people_code": 83}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `script` tag is above `body` tag. So the script executes before the form is loaded in the DOM. Put your `script` tag at the end of your `body` tag and you will get your desired output.

Also, you will need to parse the value from each input field separately and construct `formData` if you need to get your desired data format.

1. Remove `type="POST"` in your  tag.
2. Call you method `onclick` of submit button
3. Return `false` from the method so you don't trigger default browser form submit.

Take a look at this code.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
  <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>

  <body>

    <form class="myForm" id="myForm">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Store</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="store_code">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="example-number-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">companies</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="company_code">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="example-number-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">People</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="people_code">
      </div>

      <input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="submitForm();">
    </form>

    <script>
      function submitForm() {
        formData = {};
        formData['store_code'] = $("#myForm ").find('input[name="store_code"]').val();
        formData['company_code'] = $("#myForm ").find('input[name="company_code"]').val();
        formData['people_code'] = $("#myForm ").find('input[name="people_code"]').val();
        console.log(formData);

        $.ajax({
          url: "myurlfortesting.com",
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);

          }
        });

        // important so you don't submit the form after the ajax call
        return false;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: This gives the format [{"name":"store_code","value":""},{"name":"company_code","value":""},{"name":"people_code","value":""}]. I would just want [{"store_code":"mystore", "company_code": 5, "people_code": 4}]

Comment: @jumpman8947 I have updated the code. It should now give you the data format you require.

Answer (score 0):

try this below. I have process the form action after button onclick. I f you need change to submit.

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
        <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
        <script>

    function process()
    {       


         formData = {};
          var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());
          $.ajax({
                url: "myurlfortesting.com",
                data: formData,
                dataType : 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (response) {
                  console.log(response);

                }
            });
            alert(formData)

    }
</script>

  <body>

        <form class="myForm" id = "myForm" method="POST" >
            <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Store</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text"   name="store_code">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="example-number-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">companies</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="number"  name="company_code">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="example-number-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">People</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="number"   name="people_code">
          </div>


            <input value="button" type="submit" onclick="process();">
        </form>
```

Comment: This gives format [{"name":"store_code","value":"wrefds"},{"name":"company_code","value":"2"},{"name":"people_code","value":"4"}]. I am looking for a format that looks like '{"store_code": "New York", "company_code": 55, "people_code": 83}'